# Swift calculates wrong size of struct

Tags: xcode, swift, struct, sizeof

Today I encountered a problem with Swift structs.
See the following struct for example:

```
struct TestStruct {
    var test: UInt16
    var test2: UInt32
}
```

I would assume that the size of this struct in total is 6 bytes, because UInt16 is 2 bytes and UInt32 is 4 bytes large.

The following code prints 6 (which is correct):

```
println(sizeof(UInt32) + sizeof(UInt16))
```

But if I check the size of the struct with

```
println(sizeof(TestStruct))
```

it prints 8 and not 6.

If I try the same with the following struct:

```
struct TestStruct2 {
    var test: UInt16
    var test2: UInt16
    var test3: UInt16
}
```

Then

```
println(sizeof(TestStruct2))
```

prints the correct value: 6. But the size of TestStruct should be the same as the size of TestStruct2.

Why is the first struct 8 bytes large?
Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

(tested with Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a) on OS X Mavericks, normal command line application for Mac)

Comment: Google "struct alignment" and you'll see the reason. It's a general behavior. For example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71kf49f1.aspx

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898277/why-does-some-types-float80-have-a-memory-alignment-bigger-than-word-size.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I wasn't aware of this, sorry. I'm still new to lower level languages like C and Objective-C. But then, how can I get data from NSData into this aligned struct? If I use data.getBytes(&aStruct, length: sizeof(AStruct)) then I have wrong values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because Swift aligns `UInt32` field at a 4-byte boundary by inserting a two-byte "gap" between `UInt16` and `UInt32`. If you switch the fields so that the 32-bit field comes first, the gap would be eliminated:

```
struct TestStruct1 {
    var test: UInt16
    var test2: UInt32
}
println(sizeof(TestStruct1)) // <<== Prints 8

struct TestStruct2 {
    var test2: UInt32
    var test: UInt16
}
println(sizeof(TestStruct2)) // <<== Prints 6
```

You can also place another `UInt16` into that gap without changing the size of your structure:

```
struct TestStruct3 {
    var test0: UInt16
    var test1: UInt16
    var test2: UInt32
}
println(sizeof(TestStruct3)) // <<== Prints 8
```

> But then, how can I get data from `NSData` into this aligned struct? If I use `data.getBytes(&aStruct, length: sizeof(AStruct))` then I have wrong values.

Not necessarily: if you saved `AStruct` using the same method, then the gaps would be there in `NSData` as well, so obtaining your binary data would be like placing "a cookie cutter" onto pre-filled array of bytes with the same alignment.

Comment: Thanks! But what if I can't switch the fields. Take the DNS resource record for example, it has 16bit name/pointer, 16bit type and 16bit class then followed by a 32bit ttl field, then a 16bit length field and some more fields. If I have the "data" for this record in an NSData object, how can I do something like `data.getBytes(&aStruct, length: sizeof(AStruct))`? Currently I get wrong values for ttl and length because of this alignment.

Comment: An interesting fact (I think) is that the Swift `sizeof()` function does *not* include the *trailing* struct padding – so it is different from the C `sizeof`. For this one needs `strideof()`. This was discussed in https://devforums.apple.com/message/1086107#1086107.

Comment: @user4650218 If the data format is specified for you at the byte level, you shouldn't try to place it in a typed data structure directly. Take the array of bytes, and interpret your structure one field at a time: read the first 16 bit, interpret it as the name; then take the next 16 bit, and interpret it as a type; continue until the entire structure is interpreted. You can assign fields that you read to fields in your `struct`, but one at a time.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Thanks, I will do it this way. Unfortunatly, the "fill struct directly with bytes" way doesn't seem to work in all cases.

Comment: @user4650218: In addition, you should think about the *byte order*. Is the byte order in a DNS record necessarily the same as your host byte order? There are OSReadXXX utility functions which take care of this (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/libkern/libkern/OSByteOrder.h).

Comment: @MartinR: I was already converting the byteorder with CFSwapInt16BigToHost, but the OSRead function seem to be a better way.